# Android - Jetpack Navigation

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack-navigation

After creating a new project and select Navigation Drawer Activity using Kotlin language in Android Studio, the navigation is working like a charm. But when I generate the same project with Java language, it won't navigate to another fragment. What's wrong with this? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please provide more information such as Exception stacktrace, code which cause problem or the things you tried to fix it

Comment: I just create a new project with Navigation Drawer Activity and Java language, but when I click menu, it's not working. I'm not add some code or anything. It's just a fresh project @SanketBhat

Comment: @HusniKamal : If you don't provide more information it's impossible for anybody to tell what's wrong on your end and it's likely that the question gets closed. If you don't know what the relevant code is, maybe uploading the project to github would allow people to see the problem.

Comment: "After creating a new project" is not clear? It's ok and thanks for the response :) @Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the same issue.

#### My solution is:

Modify main_activity.xml: move NavigationView tag to the end of DrawerLayout

#### How to get this issue

environment:

- Android Studio: 3.5
- compileSdkVersion: 29
- buildToolsVersion: "29.0.0"
- targetSdkVersion: 29

steps:

- Step in Android Studio

  - File -> new -> new Module -> Phone & Tablet Module -> Next -> input "test" as Application/Library name -> Next -> Navigation Drawer Activity -> Next - > Finish
  - Select module "test" and Click `Run button`
- Step in android phone

  - the page is showing HomeFragment by default
  - click `menu button` to slide in the DrawerLayout 
        [image: menu]
  - click `gallery` in the menu
        [image: gallery]
  - **the DrawerLayout closed but fragment has not change to GalleryFragment**

#### Solution

Finally, i found the solution:

**Modify main_activity.xml: move NavigationView tag to the end of DrawerLayout**

android studio generated the default main_activity.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

we should change it like this(move `NavigationView` to the end of `DrawerLayout`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

#### How this issue comes

We can find the reason with source code of DrawerLayout and ViewDragHelper:

DrawerLayout

```java
public class DrawerLayout extends ViewGroup {
    //..........
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getActionMasked();
        //.........
        boolean interceptForTap = false;

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();
                if (mScrimOpacity > 0) {
                    /////////////////
                    //
                    //  take a look at: ViewDragHelper.findTopChildUnder(x, y) 
                    //  it finds child from last to first
                    //
                    /////////////////
                    final View child = mLeftDragger.findTopChildUnder((int) x, (int) y);
                    if (child != null && isContentView(child)) {
                        // if child is the contentView of DrawerLayout, intercept it
                        interceptForTap = true;
                    }
                }
                //.........
                break;
            }
            //...........
        }

        return interceptForDrag || interceptForTap || hasPeekingDrawer() || mChildrenCanceledTouch;
    }
    //...........
}
```

ViewDragHelper

```java
public class ViewDragHelper {
    //.........
    @Nullable
    public View findTopChildUnder(int x, int y) {
        final int childCount = mParentView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = childCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final View child = mParentView.getChildAt(mCallback.getOrderedChildIndex(i));
            if (x >= child.getLeft() && x < child.getRight()
                    && y >= child.getTop() && y < child.getBottom()) {
                return child;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    //........
}
```

Comment: Update: When I create a new project with Navigation Drawer Activity, the activity_main has changed, same as your code @billy